# Does it matter whether a compiled C program ends in .o?

Tags: c, gcc

For a hello world program, `hello.c`, does it matter if I compile it to a file name ending in `.o`? Or is it just a convention? E.g. should I do this:

```
gcc -o hello.o hello.c
```

Or this:

```
gcc -o hello hello.c
```

In a Linux environment

Comment: Ah, I think I misunderstood the compilation process then. So you create object files (`.o`) using -c, but otherwise you're compiling directly into binary when you do `gcc -o hello hello.c`, right?

Comment: @SupportUkraine Well, if you're running on Windows, the OS is going to get confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The situation here is a bit confusing because there are two kinds of "object files" — those that are truly intermediate object files (the ones normally ending in `.o`), and final executables.

You can use a typical command-line C compiler in two ways.  You can compile to an intermediate object file, using the `-c` option, and then "link" to a final executable as a second step:

```
cc -c -o hello.o hello.c    # step 1
cc -o hello hello.o         # step 2
```

Or you can compile and link in one fell swoop:

```
cc -o hello hello.c         # step 3
```

In the first case, when you compile and link in separate steps, the extension `.o` for the intermediate object file is the very strong convention by which everybody knows that it is in fact an intermediate object file.  Notice the difference between steps 2 and 3.  In step 3, the way the compiler knows it has some compiling to do is the extension `.c`.  In step 2, on the other hand, the extension `.o` tells it the file is already compiled, and merely needs to be linked.

(Footnotes: Actually the compiler might assume in step 2 that any unrecognized filename was an intermediate object file to be linked.  Also, we're talking about Unix here.  Under Windows, the conventional extension for intermediate object files is `.obj`.)

Also, as you may know, the extension `.o` is very much the default when compiling only.  In step 1, it would have sufficed to just say `cc -c hello.c`.

The advantage to "separate compilation" is that it gives you a lot more flexibility.  If you have a larger program, made from several source files, you could recompile everything, all at once, every time, like this:

```
cc -o program file1.c file2.c file3.c
```

But if you compile separately, like this:

```
cc -c file1.c
cc -c file2.c
cc -c file3.c
cc -o program file1.o file2.o file3.o
```

then later, when you make a change to, say, `file2.c`, you can take a shortcut and only recompile that one file.  (This does come at the cost of some disk space, to keep all those intermediate `.o` files around, and some complexity and extra typing, which for larger programs you usually let a build program like `make` take care of for you.)

Another thing you can do is to compile the same file multiple ways.  For example, I often find myself wanting to test a utility function in a "standalone" way.  As an (unrealistically simple) example, suppose that `file3.c` contains a function to multiply a number by two:

```
int doubleme(int x)
{
    return x * 2;
}
```

Suppose that, elsewhere in `file1.c` and `file2.c`, whenever I want to multiply an integer by 2, I call my `doubleme` function.  (Obviously this is completely silly and unrealistic, but it's just an example.)

But suppose you want a way to *test* the `doubleme` function, in a standalone way.  I will often do something like this.  At the end of `file3.c`, I will add:

```
#ifdef TEST_MAIN

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int x = atoi(argv[1]);
    printf("doubleme(%d) = %d\n", x, doubleme(x));
}

#endif
```

Now I can compile `file3.c` in two different ways.  If I compile it normally, like this:

```
cc -c file3.c
```

then I get `file3.o`, containing the compiled version of the `doubleme` function, that I can link in when I build `myprogram`.  Or, I can say

```
cc -c -DTEST_MAIN -o file3_test.o file3.c
cc -o file3_test file3_test.o
```

and then I can invoke things like

```
file3_test 55
```

to test out the function.

Comment: Is there any advantage to compiling and linking in separate steps?

Comment: Thanks for the clarificatory edits! One more question: where you've done `cc -o program file1.c file2.c file3.c`, presumably this couldn't be used if file1, file2 and file3 were all separate programs you wanted to compile? As "program" would be overwritten thrice

Comment: @Lou If "file1, file2 and file3 are all separate programs" — meaning that they all contain their own `main()` — the problem you have if you do `cc -o program file1.c file2.c file3.c` is that you get an error from the linker along the lines of "error" multiple definitions of `main`".

Comment: Yes, this is what I've encountered. I was wondering if there was a one-line syntactic sugar to compile e.g. file1.c file2.c and file3.c (each containing their own `main` functions as you say,) into their own executables with the same name, minus .c extension

Comment: @Lou Ah, I see.  No, there is no built-in way to do that with `cc` alone.  If I had to do that, I'd use some on-the-fly `sh` programming: `for f in file1.c file2.c and file3.c; do cc -o $(basename $f .c) $f; done`.  Or, if I wanted to get really crazy, `for f in *.c; do …`.

Comment: Got it. I thought about doing something similar, but at that point I should probably learn the Make solution. Anyway that's thoroughly another question - thanks all for the constructive and helpful input! :)

Answer (score 2):

By convention extension (in linux at least) `.o` implies an Object File, not an executable. So, yes, you can use this extension, as in `gcc -o hello.o hello.c`, but it's misleading and a bad idea. Better to do `gcc -o hello hello.c`.

However, if you are building the object file (i.e. compile only, not link) you would use the `-c` option, as in `gcc -c hello.c`, which will create the object file `hello.o`.

(Just summarizing what's already in the comments.)

Comment: Thank you for clarifying my misunderstandings :)

Comment: @SupportUkraine You're absolutely correct. Answer corrected.

Answer (score 2):

By convention extension (in linux at least) .o implies an Object File, not an executable. So, yes, you can use this extension, as in gcc -o hello.o hello.c, but it's misleading and a bad idea. Better to do gcc -o hello hello.c.

Comment: Is this a copy-and-paste of Anthony Kelly's answer, or were both answers copied form a (now-deleted) comment?